# Allowing Users logged in with multiple accounts at once to the same Django site

Tags: python, django, session, django-sessions, django-users

I'm creating a widget that gets installed on various different sites and I need distinct users for each site. Problem is, the same person browsing might have 2 different sites open at once that use my widget. This means that I need users to be logged in with multiple accounts simultaneously to the same Django site.

From my understanding, Django usually assumes that only 1 user is logged in per session.

What's the simplest and most effective way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up storing the per-site data in the user's session, i.e. `session['site_id_1'] = user_obj_1`, `session['site_id_2'] = user_obj_2`, etc...

Instead of logging in, I just store the user data in the appropriate key. Instead of logging out, I delete the key for the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to rewrite the session middleware. In the default implementation the session is stored in the database, the session_key is saved in a cookie and the cookie_name is defined in `settings.py`.

So if you write your own session middleware, you can define different cookie names for every site and retrieve the session from the database accordingly. [django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py) is a good template.